# Program still picks up letter, when I specifically tell it not to

Tags: java

In one of the lines, at least. Heres the whole code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestChar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        String myChar ;

        System.out.println(" Please input a character from your keyboard : ");
              myChar = input.nextLine();
              char c = myChar.charAt(0);
                 System.out.println(" You entered " + myChar);

                 System.out.println(" is it a letter? " + Character.isLetter(c));

                 System.out.println(" is it a number? " + Character.isDigit(c));        

                 System.out.println(" is it in lowercase? " + Character.isLowerCase(c));

                 System.out.println(" is it in uppercase? " + Character.isUpperCase(c));

                 if (Character.isLetter(c))
                           System.out.println(" In Upper Case : " + Character.toUpperCase(c) + ". And in lower case : " + Character.toLowerCase(c)) ;


               if 
                 (Character.isDigit(c) && !myChar.equals(Character.isLetter(c)))
                     System.out.println( myChar + " is a number.") ;                                           

              if  (!myChar.equals(Character.isLetter(c)) && !myChar.equals(Character.isDigit(c)))
                       System.out.println( myChar + " is neither a number nor letter.");

   }   

  }
```

Another school assignment of mine. The last line of code picks up a letter, when (I think) I've specifically told it not too. I am an extreme novice at coding, so go easy on my code.

Comment: if-else statements. Very useful, but be careful to only compare else cases for the same variables, meaning don't do an if statement on an integer, then to an else-if on a string or another, unrelated integer. Have fun learning!

Answer (score 4):

`Character.isLetter()` and `Character.isDigit()` return a boolean value, which you're subsequently comparing to `myChar`, which is (somewhat misleadingly) a String. Obviously, they will never be equal.

Here's a correct and simplified version:

```
if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
    System.out.println(" In Upper Case : " + Character.toUpperCase(c) + ". And in lower case : " + Character.toLowerCase(c));
} else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    System.out.println(c + " is a number.");
} else {
    System.out.println(c + " is neither a number nor letter.");
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes somewhat more sense. Thanks!